# unable to get Yahoo mail by Message-ID using mailkit

Tags: imap, yahoo, mailkit

I want to fetch mail item by Message-Id using following code.

```
     var messageId = messageIdStringValue.DecryptFromBase64();
          var newId = "<" + messageId + ">";
        var matches = Client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.HeaderContains("Message-ID", newId));
        foreach (var uid in matches)
        {

            var message = Client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);

        }
```

It's working fine with Gmail by there is no result for Yahoo mail.I should mention that I can get All mail items but the problem is in fetching the single message.Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jstedfast I've found that the best way for searching mail item is by UniqueId not by the Message-ID as the search command maybe return no result in that way for different servers.
following code works fine for all servers:

```
 foreach (var item in Client.Inbox.Fetch(new[] { uId }, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure))
        {
          var message = Client.Inbox.GetMessage(item.UniqueId)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Different IMAP servers implement SEARCH differently.

That said, why are you base64 decoding the message-id value? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also Base64 isn't an encryption,  it's an encoding.

Comment: Different servers do differ, but not being able to `SEARCH HEADER MESSAGE-ID <foo>` would be remarkable. I shouldn't wonder if something's wrong with the `messageIdStringValue`.

Comment: Yea, I'm surprised by the same. I think I've heard that some implementations don't like the <>'s, but I'm not confident in that memory.

Comment: 'messageIdStringValue' is the encrypted Id as a parameter. after decoding, it will be the exact messaged-Id which I want to search. I've implemented searching without < > too, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why the message-id is base64 encoded in the first place, it's not like it's binary data.